# Media queries working fine in browser but not

Tags: ipad, responsive-design, media-queries

I've developed this page:

http://bluebeam.com/us/support/ipad/

The media queries are working fine in every browser but when I test it on an ipad it does nothing... It just reverts back to normal CSS. I've cleared browsing data on the iPad without results. I can see it working on my iPhone.

Can anyone spot an issue with my code?

Edit: the first query (horizontal layout) is working. But the second is not triggering when I flip the ipad (vertical layout).

Comment: For some reason the typography is the only thing that won't change on the iPad... I can change colors no problem in the media query but the typography remains the default (which is really the only thing I NEED to change).

Answer (score 0):

If I remember correctly the iPad swaps the width/height values when the orientation changes.  I would try this:

```
/* portrait*/
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px)

/* landscape */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 1024px) 
and (max-device-width : 768px)
```

Its been a year since I faced a similar problem so I could be a bit behind the times.

Comment: For some reason whenever I include **only** screen it breaks the queries. I know this is the proper way to reference the queries so I'm wondering why it breaks them. Also min-**device**-width breaks them too. I tried them without those and it didn't work it only used the first query again.

Comment: Just try min-width and max-width.

Comment: Yeah I did that. It still only reverts to the first query, in both orientations.